# JSON: Inserir um elemento em um determinado index (ou key)

Tags: javascript, html

```
var fields = [
    {
        "Category": "Computers",
        "Price": "125.60",
        "Book ID": "1",
        "Book Name": "Computer Architecture"
    },
    {
        "Book ID": "2",
        "Category": "Programming",
        "Price": "56.00",
        "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book"
    },
    {
        "Price": "210.40",
        "Book ID": "3",
        "Category": "Science",
        "Book Name": "Popular Science"
    }
];

if(fields.length > 0){
    var newField = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        var field = fields[i];
        fields[i]["abobora"] = 'abobora teste';
    }
    var newField = fields;
    console.log(newField);
}
```

- Como eu adiciono na segunda posição de cada elemento? O exemplo acima que fiz sempre adiciona no último elemento de cada objeto

Exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/a6dx81fy/

- Eu queria que o objeto fosse adicionado em um determinado index, como exemplo abaixo:

  ```
  var fields = [
  {
      "Category": "Computers",
      "Price": "125.60",
      "abobora": 'abobora teste', <- gerar nesse index
      "Book ID": "1",
      "Book Name": "Computer Architecture"
  },
  {
      "Book ID": "2",
      "Category": "Programming",
      "abobora": 'abobora teste',  <- gerar nesse index
      "Price": "56.00",
      "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book"
  },
  {
      "Price": "210.40",
      "Book ID": "3",
      "abobora": 'abobora teste', <- gerar nesse index
      "Category": "Science",
      "Book Name": "Popular Science"
  }];
  ```

Comment: carlos, não abandone as suas perguntas. Marque uma resposta como a certa, ou se nenhuma resolveu, questione. Abandonar perguntas não faz parte do propósito da comunidade. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar a propriedade e utilizar o segundo parâmetro de [`JSON.stringify`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) 
 para transformar o objeto em `String` e manter uma ordem na exibição do seu JSON, passando um Array com as propriedades na ordem que você deseja que elas sejam exibidas. Logo depois, você usa [`JSON.parse`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) novamente para transformar a `String` em `Object`.

```js
var field = {
    "Category": "Computers",
    "Price": "125.60",
    "Book ID": "1",
    "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
    "abobora": 'abobora teste'
};

field = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(field, ["Category", "Price", "abobora", "Book ID", "Book Name"]));

console.log(field);
```

Isso não é necessariamente "mudar o index", pois em objetos `JSON` não há indices numéricos para serem acessados como no `Array`, a não ser que você os crie para essa finalidade. O que isso faz é simplesmente mudar a ordem de exibição.

Answer (score 0):

A sua pergunta é ambígua, há duas interpretações, a primeira é que você quer inserir um novo par chave/valor no objeto, porém quer adicionar em uma posição específica e não simplesmente adicionar o novo par chave/valor.

A segunda interpretação é que você quer adicionar um novo objeto ao array de objetos, porém quer adicioná-lo não no fim, mas em um índice específico.

Para a primeira (que não faz sentido, pois no objeto o acesso aos valores depende da chave e não da posição em que estão, o papel de "lista encadeada" no JavaScript é do Array):

Simplemente crie um novo objeto, assim:

```
let objAntigo = { category: "categoria", price: 10, bookId: 3 };

let novoObj = {
  category: objAntigo.category,
  abobora: "abobora",
  price: objAntigo.price, 
  bookId: objAntigo.bookId
}
```

Para a segunda interpretação, você pode usar o método splice() do Array JavaScript, assim:

```
let arrayAntigo = ["objeto um", "objeto dois", "objeto tres"];
let removidos = arrayAntigo.splice(1, 0, "objeto quatro");

console.log(arrayAntigo) // ["objeto um", "objeto quatro", "objeto dois", 
"objeto tres"]
```

Comment: Documentação do splice() https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

Você pode reestruturar o objeto fazendo um laço `for in` concatenando os valores e inserir a nova chave "abobora" quando o loop estiver na segunda chave fazendo uma concatenação numa variável. Depois basta usar `JSON.parse` pra converter a variável para objeto no objeto array `newField`.

**Veja:**

```js
var fields = [
    {
        "Category": "Computers",
        "Price": "125.60",
        "Book ID": "1",
        "Book Name": "Computer Architecture"
    },
    {
        "Book ID": "2",
        "Category": "Programming",
        "Price": "56.00",
        "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book"
    },
    {
        "Price": "210.40",
        "Book ID": "3",
        "Category": "Science",
        "Book Name": "Popular Science"
    }
];

if(fields.length > 0){
   var newField = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
      var field = fields[i];
   
      var novo = "";
      var x=0;
      for(var idx in field){
         var item_atual = '"'+idx+'":"'+field[idx]+'",';
         novo += item_atual + (x < 1 || x > 1 ? '' : '"abobora": "abobora teste",');
         x++;
      }
   
      novo = '{'+novo.substring(0,novo.length-1)+'}'; // removo a última vírgula
   
      newField[i] = JSON.parse(novo); // crio o objeto json
   
   }
   console.log("Original", fields);
   console.log("Novo", newField);
   console.log(newField[0]["abobora"]);
}
```